# Replacement for self-hosted SFTP after migration to Heroku

Tags: heroku, sftp

Our app is currently self-hosted and we run an SFTP server on the machine to accept incoming files from several third parties.

We are now migrating the app to Heroku. We still need to be able to accept these incoming files from  third parties. How can we accept these files in a way that works well with the Heroku way of doing things?

Is there a Heroku add-on that can fill the gap? Are there other third-party services that work well with Heroku/Amazon ecosystem?

Comment: Annoying that someone downvoted the question without comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest create an EC2 instance(s) that front the S3 bucket for storage. There are many [instructions](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_s3_sftp) on how to do that online.

Comment: This is the solution we went with. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one possibility is to set up an Amazon EC2 instance, which seems to support SFTP as a login mechanism: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=444559

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a dedicated SFTP service